# How do I edit / add fcitx5 input method icon (in Xfce)? I can see that Mozc and Pinyin have icons

Tags: xfce, input-method, fcitx

I can see that there are multiple files in `/usr/share/fcitx5/inputmethod` including `mozc.conf` and `pinyin.conf` doing this. However, how do I set icon for `Keyboard - Thai`?

Also, I want colored icon for Pinyin in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/fcitx-pinyin.png`, instead of the normal monochrome one.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Xubuntu, but fcitx is install manually.

Comment: All I can find about Pinyin says it is for Chinese only.

Comment: Mozc is for Japanese. But I am Thai, and I am learning both Japanese and Chinese.

Comment: I just looked at Fcitx, and couldn't find any Thai input method either. Possibly you want to try IBus instead. When looking at `ibus-setup` I see multiple Thai options. at least in 20.10 and 21.04. And e.g. `ibus-libpinyin` and `ibus-mozc` are well maintained packages.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks, but I do can use Thai in fcitx by default. Anyways, I switched to `ibus` with `sunpinyin` and `mozc` and case-closed. (But `sogoupinyin` is only on `fcitx`'s side.)

Comment: @Polv: As regards `sogoupinyin` - yes. There are reasons why Fcitx is especially popular among Chinese Linux users.